# Nonlinear time dependent equation in simulink

Tags: simulation, control-system, simulink

My question is about time varying nonlinear equations in simulating of them in simulink. in nonlinear time independent equations x,Dx,D^2(x) are made with multiple integral block like the picture in below:
[image]

For nonlinear time varying equations like below, for making D^2(x(t)),D(x(t)) and x(t) what blocks should be used for having varying 't' in equation and how?
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45531/nonlinear-time-varying-equation-in-simulink

Comment: @JonRB the questioner probably offers his question here and there in hope to get out of  some black hole in the basic knowledge. I let him to find something positive here, because thislike calculations have been practical also in analog electronics - at least for me.

Comment: I face this question in simulating of a control system

Comment: Multiplication block?

Comment: Sorry @Rwy5, you cannot cross post on stack exchange, choose one question to delete so there is only one.

Comment: @JonRB and other friends, this question is related to its tags that here there are.

Answer (score 2):

Seems a homework. So no full solutions will be given.

This is a simple two state variable problem. The general solution is calculated followingly:

[image]

Calc diffs is a block diagram which takes X1, X2 , possible external signals and constants as inputs, the outputs are the derivatives of the state variables. You need seemingly  two summing junctions, 3 polarity inversions, one multiplication, linear time ramp generator (=-2t) and an exponential function block for exp(-2t).

Do not forget to set integration method, sample rate, plot scaling and the initial values to integrators.

NOTE: I have not a modern Matlab, not even a real thing, but only an ancient low cost copy. Real and new Matlab can have some things named differently.

ADDED due the comments:

You really have missed something essential about simulation. Hopefully the following diagram helps you to catch it. The integrators accumulate the time dependent inputs.

[image]

Your system gives zero output if there are zero initial values in the integrators. I had the following simulation parameters:

- time start = 0, end=2 seconds
- sample rate = 10kHz (simulation step = 0.1ms)
- integration = trapezoidal
- initial value =1 in both integrators

Comment: Except for exponential term in the equation that needs clock for giving time to it,  x1 & x2 that are time dependents , do they need term of time to giving them or they don't need it? If need, how?

Comment: @Rwy5 You must find time independent exponential function block and put into it -2t. There should be a signal source for time ramp. As well you can take an integrator which has input =-2 and initial value = zero. If you find variable t as a function generator block  you can multiply it by -2. You must calculate the derivatives with time dependent functions. That's the most common  form of  simulation.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks, What I understand is that for terms of x1(t) and x2(t) in time dependent equations like above that we don't have relations of them with time, there's no need to term of t and just integral blocks that you show is enough. is it true? What is the name of your simulator?

Comment: @Rwy5 It's name is VisSim. It originally was intended to be a simplified low cost alternative to Matlab's Simulink. It hasn't the power of Matlab in the back room, VisSim evolved gradually and got quite powerful extensions for different purposes. About one year ago VisSim was sold to another owner. See http://web.solidthinking.com/vissim-is-now-solidthinking-embed. It got a new name, integrated to a bigger collection of software and the pricing & licensing changed.

Comment: @Rwy5 The integrating blocks take the time into the account without a need to insert time to anything. The decaying exponential function is constructed from a preset time dependent function block. Very often also some pulses and sinusoidal signal sources are needed, but here I used only the ramp.